# Definition of "visit"

Tags: visa, uk-visa, marriage

I am an expat living in an EEA country and currently applying for a marriage visa to the UK. In the visa application, they ask me about the last three visits I made to each country of the EEA over the last 10 years. Should I take that to mean my last 4 years, in which I lived in this country, as a single visit? Or should I interpret that as meaning each continuous interval of time in this country as a visit? I could not find their definition of visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UK Immigration Immigration Rules for Visitors state:

> This route is for a person who wants to visit the UK for a temporary period, (usually for up to 6 months), for purposes such as tourism, visiting friends or family, carrying out a business activity, or undertaking a short course of study.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

You are not a ‘visitor’ in the EEA country where you reside. The UK visa application is asking about the last three visits you have made to *other* EEA countries during the last 10 years. If eg you visited the country where you now reside *before* you became a resident there, you would include it. Otherwise only include *other* EEA countries.